# How to enable Groovy comments in SublimeText 3 on a Mac?

Tags: macos, groovy, sublimetext, sublimetext3

Currently i am using SublimeText 3 on a Mac but i am unable to 'comment' existing Groovy code. The menu and the shortcut keys do not place the actual '//' comments when i use the menu or the shortcut key. I have searched but i only found solutions to correct this in SublimeText 2. These solutions to copy some Java comments do not work.

Any solution on how Groovy comments can be enabled in SublimeText 3?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

These instructions are for OS X, but the same general method applies to any platform.

Go to **`Sublime Text -> Preferences -> Browse Packages...`** to open up the `Packages` folder (`~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages`). Create a new folder in `Packages` named `Groovy`. Next, create a new file in Sublime with XML syntax and the following contents:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>name</key>
    <string>Comments</string>
    <key>scope</key>
    <string>source.groovy</string>
    <key>settings</key>
    <dict>
        <key>shellVariables</key>
        <array>
            <dict>
                <key>name</key>
                <string>TM_COMMENT_START</string>
                <key>value</key>
                <string>// </string>
            </dict>
        </array>
    </dict>
    <key>uuid</key>
    <string>D3A56263-A730-4C6E-B8F2-E65FEE21870B</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Save this file as `Packages/Groovy/Comments.tmPreferences`. You might get a warning about saving the file with a `.xml` suffix, just ignore it and use `.tmPreferences`.

And now you should be able to hit <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>/</kbd> and insert comments.

Comment: Works as well on Linux using the following path:
~/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages/

Comment: Worked exactly as described. Thanks!